# Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, redux, paypal, react-redux

Issue with adding PayPal Button to OrderPage:

> Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.

In console:

> "The above error occurred in the component: 
>  at e
> ([https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id='#my](https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=%27#my) client id') 
>  at
> PayPalButton (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:437215:5)"
>
> **And while writting in terminal "npm i react-paypal-button-v2":** 
>  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
>  npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve
> dependency tree
>  npm ERR!
>  npm ERR! While resolving:
> sklep@0.1.0
>  npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
>  npm ERR!
> node_modules/react
>  npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root
> project
>  npm ERR!
>  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from
> react-paypal-button-v2@2.6.2
>  npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2
>  npm ERR!
> react-paypal-button-v2@"^2.6.2" from the root project

```
import React from 'react'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import {detailsOrder} from "../actions/orderActions";
import LoadingBoxWhite from "../components/LoadingBoxWhite";
import {SecondaryNavbar} from "../components/Navbar/secondaryNavbar";
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {PayPalButton} from "react-paypal-button-v2";

export default function OrderPage (props) {

const orderId = props.match.params.id;
const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);
const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails;
const dispatch = useDispatch();


useEffect(() => {
    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get('/api/config/paypal');
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${data}`;
            script.async = true;
            script.onload = () => {
                setSdkReady(true);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    if (!order || (order && order._id !== orderId)) {
        dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
    } else {
        if (!order.isPaid) {
            if (!window.paypal) {
                addPayPalScript();
            } else {
                setSdkReady(true);
            }
        }
    }
}, [dispatch, orderId, sdkReady, order]);

const successPaymentHandler = () => {
    //
}


const setDate = (date) => {
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit',day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'}).format(date);
}


return loading ? (<LoadingBoxWhite/>) : error ? (<MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>) : (
    <div>
        <SecondaryNavbar/>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row top">
                <div className="col-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div className="card card-body">
                                <h1 style={{marginBottom: '10px', color: 'black'}}>Numer Zamówienia: {order._id}</h1>
                                <h2>Dostawa</h2>
                                <p>
                                    <strong>Imię i Nazwisko: </strong> {order.shippingAddress.name} <br/>
                                    <strong>Adres Wysyłki: </strong> {order.shippingAddress.address}, &nbsp;
                                    {order.shippingAddress.city}, &nbsp;
                                    {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}, &nbsp;
                                    {order.shippingAddress.country}
                                </p>

                                {order.isDelivered ? <MessageBox variant="success">Dostarczono: {setDate(order.deliveredAt)}</MessageBox>: <MessageBox variant="danger">Zamówienie Niedostarczone</MessageBox>}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div className="card card-body">
                                <h2>Metoda Płatności</h2>
                                <p>
                                    {order.paymentMethod} <br/>
                                </p>
                                {order.isPaid ? <MessageBox variant="success">Zapłacono: {setDate(order.paidAt)}</MessageBox>: <MessageBox variant="danger">Zamówienie Nieopłacone</MessageBox>}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div className="card card-body">
                                <h2>Zamówienie</h2>
                                <ul>
                                    {order.orderItems.map((item) => (
                                        <li key={item.product}>
                                            <div className="row  borderwhite">
                                                <div>
                                                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}> <img
                                                        className="small hoverbig"
                                                        src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/' + item.image}
                                                        alt={item.name}
                                                    /></Link>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="min-30">
                                                    <h2><Link to={`/product/${item.product}`} className="hoverred blacked" >{item.name}</Link></h2>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="blacked"><p>{item.qty} x {item.price} zł = {item.qty * item.price} zł</p></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    ))}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="col-1">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <h2>Podsumowanie Zamówienia</h2>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div>Suma</div>
                                        <div>{order.itemsPrice} zł</div>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div>Koszt Dostawy</div>
                                    <div>{order.shippingPrice} zł</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div>VAT</div>
                                    <div>{order.taxPrice} zł</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div><strong>Razem</strong></div>
                                    <div><strong> {order.totalPrice} zł</strong></div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            {!order.isPaid && (
                                <li>
                                    {!sdkReady ? (
                                        <LoadingBox/>
                                    ) : (
                                        <PayPalButton amount={order.totalPrice} onSuccess={successPaymentHandler}/>
                                    )}
                                </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this project. You have a newer version of react than Paypal-button requires. You just need to change react.js and react-dom.js version in package.json file. I wrote "16.14.0" and it works.